# simple grunt-copy .txt file becoming empty

Tags: gruntjs

I am learning grunt and trying to do what I thought would be simple: copy a text file.

```
copy: {
    main: {
        src: 'app/text.txt',
        dest: 'build/copied.txt'
    }
}
```

No errors are produced when run and the file is "copied" but `build/copied.txt` contains a single period character rather than the contents of the `app/text.txt` file.

Why is/would it do this?

**Followup Edit**

1. Firstly I had `grunt-copy` not `grunt-contrib-copy` module installed. This works differently and has some punctuation options, which I believe is where the mysterious period was coming from.
2. 2nd + facepalm: I had a typo, `app/test.txt` should have been `text`. This was not obvious to anyone in this QA as I didn't post my file list. But...
3. Use the `--verbose` tag to debug as it showed a missing src, which led me to discover the stupid typo.

The above code **does** work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I assume you are using (grunt-contrib-copy), I debugged the issue and it seems that copying (single .txt file by name) **doesnt work** it works for .js and many other files? but you can get .txt file(s) copy to work like this, if you have problems with permissions again there is an option called **[mode](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy#mode)**.

```
copy: {
  main: {
    flatten: true,
    src: ["app/*.txt"],
    dest: "build/",
    expand: true,
    rename: function (dest, src) {
      // rename test.txt to copied.txt
      if (src === "test.txt") {
        return dest + "copied.txt";
      }
      return dest + src;
    }
  }
}
```

However I would do this kind of thing without renaming, it is obvious that `build` folder contains your copied file, so I prefer copy them as they are:

```
copy: {
  main: {
    flatten: true,
    src: ["app/*.txt"],
    dest: "build/",
    expand: true
  }
}
```

Note that because single file match `src: ["app/test.txt"]` (for .txt format) doens't work and if you have problems that it is copying too many text files, you could put it inside different folder alone and use it like this:

```
copy: {
  single: {
    flatten: true,
    src: ["app/single/*.txt"],
    dest: "build/",
    expand: true
  },
  other: {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

and with task:

```
grunt.registerTask("testCopy", ["copy:single"]);
```

and to run it:

```
grunt testCopy
```

Comment: Ahh so it is an oddity. Awesome: all 3 examples work. One question: why do you put square brackets around the src? Thanks!

Comment: oops, mostly because its an habit of mine :), I have used to copy multiple files like: src: ["app/trash/*.js", "app/another/*.md"] with this case you can probably just omit them if you like.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `copy` task only copies, not renames. Thus what you are doing is creating a directory called `copied.txt` within the `build` directory. To rename a file on copy you'll need to use the `rename` option. This is not a feature of the `copy` task, but rather a general feature of the `file` option which it uses (and many other tasks use this common option). You can see the [documentation on the Grunt site](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expandmapping) for this, just do a find on "rename" on that page.

```
copy: {
    main: {
        src: 'app/text.txt',
        dest: 'build/',
        rename: function(dest, src, options) {
            return path.join(dest, "copied.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: K it helps knowing that the rename is treated separately but if I remove the "copied.txt" (in an attempt to just copy text.txt to build/) or try the code you posted I get the error `Warning: Unable to write "build/" file (Error code: EISDIR). Use --force to continue.`.

Comment: Do you have permissions to write to that directory?  Not sure what else that could be...

Comment: Hmm well it was able to write the file with the . in it and other tasks are working ok. I also tried chmod 777 on build and build/* and still same error. This also works:
`
raa: {
    expand: true,
    flatten: true,
    src: 'app/*',
    dest: 'build/all/'
}
` as a separate target to copy.